# Giving a custom UserControl an ID in rendered HTML

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls

When I use a ASP:Calendar control, and give it an ID:

`<asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="MyCal" />`

It looks like this in the rendered html:

`<table id="NameMangled_MyCal"... />`

And I can access the element by ID in javascript like this:

`var cal= document.getElementById("<%= MyCal.ClientID%>")`

**However,** When I make a custom user control that has-a calendar:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WeeklyEventsCalendar.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WeeklyEventsCalendar" %>

<div>
    <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="InnerCal" Width="100%" OnDayRender="RenderCell" OnVisibleMonthChanged="ChangeMonth" Height="480px" />
</div>
```

And then give it an ID when I add it to my page...

`<mvs:WeeklyEventsCalendar ID="WeeklyCal" runat="server" />`

That ID doesn't show up anywhere in the rendered HTML. all I get is

`<div> stuff </div>`

When I want

`<div id="NameMangled_WeeklyCal"> stuff <div>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UserControls only render their contents, nothing else. What you could do is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WeeklyEventsCalendar.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WeeklyEventsCalendar" %>

<div id="<%= this.ControlID %>">
    <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="InnerCal" Width="100%" OnDayRender="RenderCell" OnVisibleMonthChanged="ChangeMonth" Height="480px" />
</div>
```